# Require JS optimising error for JQuery

Tags: requirejs

I am trying to minify my code using requireJS's r.js.

my **command** is

```
$node node_modules\requirejs\bin\r.js name=main out=main-built.js baseUrl=.
```

Am getting following error.

```
timers.js:103
            if (!process.listeners('uncaughtException').length) throw e;
                                                                      ^
Error: Evaluating ./lib/jquery-1.8.0.min.js as module "jquery" failed with error
: ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at Function.req.load (C:\xampp\htdocs\ember\App\js\node_modules\requirejs\bin
\r.js:2227:23)
    at Object.context.load (C:\xampp\htdocs\ember\App\js\node_modules\requirejs\b
in\r.js:1681:21)
    at Object.Module.load (C:\xampp\htdocs\ember\App\js\node_modules\requirejs\bi
n\r.js:907:29)
    at Object.Module.fetch (C:\xampp\htdocs\ember\App\js\node_modules\requirejs\b
in\r.js:897:66)
    at Object.Module.check (C:\xampp\htdocs\ember\App\js\node_modules\requirejs\b
in\r.js:927:26)
    at Object.Module.enable (C:\xampp\htdocs\ember\App\js\node_modules\requirejs\
bin\r.js:1211:22)
    at Object.context.enable (C:\xampp\htdocs\ember\App\js\node_modules\requirejs
\bin\r.js:1553:39)
    at Object.Module.enable.mod (C:\xampp\htdocs\ember\App\js\node_modules\requir
ejs\bin\r.js:1196:33)
    at g (C:\xampp\htdocs\ember\App\js\node_modules\requirejs\bin\r.js:233:23)
    at each (C:\xampp\htdocs\ember\App\js\node_modules\requirejs\bin\r.js:165:31)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some docs on using jQuery with RequireJS here:

http://requirejs.org/docs/jquery.html

Make sure your config looks something like this:

```
require.config({

paths: {
    jquery: 'lib/jquery',
    // other paths
},
shim: {
    jquery: ['jquery'],
    // plugins that depend on jquery
    slider: {
        deps: ['jquery']
    },
    moment: {
        deps: ['jquery']
    }
}
});
```